# XSL:FO Vertical Alignment of Positive and Negative Numbers

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I am trying to format this xml input:

```
<item name="foo" amt1="100" amt2="200" />
<item name="bar" amt1="-300" amt2="-400" />
```

in a pdf (using RenderX) as:

```
foo |  100  |  200
--- | ----- | -----
bar | (300) | (400)
```

but the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="item">
  ... 
    <fo:table-row>    
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block text-align="left">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block text-align="right">
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@amt1, '#,###;(#,###)')"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block text-align="right">
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@amt2, '#,###;(#,###)')"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:for-each>
```

is output as:

```
foo |   100 |   200
--- | ----- | -----
bar | (300) | (400)
```

where the positive numbers in row 1 and negative numbers in row 2 are aligned right, but I would also like them to be vertically aligned by the last integer of the number instead of the last character. The only solution I can think of is to have an xsl:choose set an additional 'padding-after' attribute on all positive integers to push them over the last integer of the negative numbers. Is there a better way to do this?

Solution:

```
<fo:block text-align="right">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@amt1, '#,###;(#,###)')"/>
    <fo:leader leader-pattern="use-content" leader-length="5pt" leader-pattern-width="5pt">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@cy_amt &lt;= '0'">)</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </fo:leader>
</fo:block>
```

Comment: See http://www.renderx.com/usecasestest.html and look at the last sample. It is decimal point alignment but a perfect example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the responses. @KevinBrown, I was able to get the leader to work. I've added that to the bottom of my question. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The list/leader solutions are not perfect from my point of view as they require the numbers to be right-aligned. Hence if you don't know how long your numbers may be, you have to leave an important horizontal space even if most of the time the numbers are small and could be closer to some label.

I use the following template which allows me to align several numbers by adding invisible zeroes on the left. So the largest number is left-aligned, and the other numbers are aligned to its decimal point.

Obvious caveats are
- you have to know what the largest number is
- negative numbers are not handled (yet this can be fixed, I may do it when I need it, I'll make sure to update this answer then)
- you have to use a font in which digits all use the same horizontal space.

```
<xsl:template name="tools_formatters_number">
  <xsl:param name="integer-positions" select="0" />
  <xsl:param name="number" />
  <xsl:param name="mask" select="'###,###,###,###,###,##0.00'" />

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:variable name="positions" select="$integer-positions + floor(($integer-positions - 1) div 3)" />

    <xsl:variable name="mask-zeroed" select="translate($mask, '#', '0')" />
    <xsl:variable name="mask-zeroed-left" select="substring-before($mask-zeroed, '.')" />
    <xsl:variable name="mask-zeroed-right" select="concat('.', substring-after($mask-zeroed, '.'))" />

    <xsl:variable name="sub-mask-zeroed-left" select="substring($mask-zeroed-left, string-length($mask-zeroed-left) - $positions + 1, $positions)" />

    <xsl:variable name="mask2" select="concat($sub-mask-zeroed-left, $mask-zeroed-right)" />
    <xsl:variable name="fnumber" select="format-number($number, $mask2)" />

    <xsl:variable name="pnumber" select="string-length(substring-before(format-number($number, $mask), '.'))" />
    <xsl:variable name="posnumber" select="$pnumber + floor(($pnumber - 1) div 3) + string-length(substring-after($fnumber, '.')) + 1" />

    <xsl:variable name="whitepart" select="substring($fnumber, 1, string-length($fnumber) - $posnumber)" />
    <xsl:variable name="blackpart" select="substring($fnumber, string-length($fnumber) - $posnumber + 1, $posnumber)" />

    <inline color="white"><xsl:value-of select="$whitepart" /></inline>
    <xsl:value-of select="$blackpart" />
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is a brief description of what each param/variable contains.

Values in braces constitute an example.

- integer-positions says how many digits need to be shown before the decimal separator. {7}
- number is the number to be shown. {4242.42}
- mask is a standard mask for formatting numbers. The template code is tailored for that mask, you can add thousand groups on the left and whatever you want on the right, but each group has to be made of exactly three digits on the left of the decimal separator. {###,###,###,###,###,##0.00}
- positions is integer-positions, taking thousand separators into consideration {9}
- mask-zeroed is mask without optional digits on the left {000,000.00}
- mask-zeroed-left is the integer part of mask-zeroed {000,000}
- mask-zeroed-right is the decimal part of mask-zeroed {.00}
- sub-mask-zeroed-left is mask-zeroed-left limited to positions digits. {0,000,000}
- mask2 adds the right part to sub-mask-zeroed-left. {0,000,000.00}
- fnumber is number formatted with mask2. {0,004,242.42}
- pnumber is the number of digits in the integer part of number {4}
- posnumber is the number of symbols that need to be shown {(5 + 3 =) 8}
- whitepart is the space part which will be printed in white {0,00}
- blackpart is the actual number {4,242.42}

Example of use:

```
<xsl:call-template name="tools_formatters_number">
  <xsl:with-param name="integer-positions" select="7" />
  <xsl:with-param name="number" select="'4242.42'" />
</xsl:call-template>
```